# ADEHabitat Smoothing parameters Sig1and2

Tags: r, gis, adehabitathr

I am trying to build some BBMM code and although it produces the outputs I want, I am having trouble figuring out the proper smoothing parameters using Sig 1 and Sig 2. When I use the liker function it produces the exact same curve for every individual, which does not seem right. I have tried playing with the Sig 2 number and range of sig1 but it does not seem to make any difference at all. What am I missing?

[image: Example data]

`#Load Package
library(BBMM)
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(adehabitatLT)

##Plot Movement Rates for individuals

ctraj <- as.ltraj(xy = coordinates(RelSPDF), date = RelSPDF$Timestamp, id =RelSPDF$Animal_ID)

is.regular(ctraj)

graphics.off()

par("mar")

par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

plotltr(ctraj)

###Establish smoother Sig1 and Sig2 parameters

x <- ctraj

lik <- liker(x, sig2 = 6, rangesig1 = c(1, 50))

xbb <- kernelbb(x, sig1 = 300, sig2 = 6, grid=1500)

image(xbb)

plot(getverticeshr(xbb, 95), add=TRUE, lwd=2)

plot(ctraj)`

[image: Sigma]

I am using R 2021.09.0, 64Bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try adjusting the `rangesig1` to a different range. This is your standard deviation. See below, which is copied from the help page. View it in R with `?liker`

```
## Field studies have shown that the mean standard deviation (relocations
## as a sample of the actual position of the animal) is equal to 58
## meters on these data (Maillard, 1996, p. 63). Therefore
sig2 <- 58

## Find the maximum likelihood estimation of the parameter sig1
## First, try to find it between 10 and 100.
liker(x, sig2 = 58, rangesig1 = c(10, 100))

## Wow! we expected a too large standard deviation! Try again between
## 1 and 10:
liker(x, sig2 = 58, rangesig1 = c(1, 10))

## So that sig1 = 6.23
```

You also need to make some adjustments to the code you have provided, including transforming your Timestamp to `POSIXct` and providing coordinates in the correct format.

Below is your code edited to do this.

```
RelSPDF<- read.csv("yourdata.csv")

#change Timestamp to POSIXct
# ymd_hms stands for year,month,day,hours,mins,secs
# Ensure this is in the correct order to match your data 

library(lubridate)
RelSPDF$Timestamp<- ymd_hms(RelSPDF$Timestamp) 

#Load Package 
#library(BBMM) # this package is no longer available
library(sp) 
library(adehabitatHR) 
library(adehabitatLT)

##Plot Movement Rates for individuals


#convert your coordinates 

xy <- RelSPDF[,c(4,3)] # 3 and 4 are the column numbers - long is x


#then set them up as an xy for the next part of your code

xy <- coordinates(xy)

####

ctraj <- as.ltraj(xy = coordinates(xy), date = RelSPDF$Timestamp, id =RelSPDF$Animal_ID)


###Establish smoother Sig1 and Sig2 parameters

par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

x <- ctraj

lik <- liker(x, sig2 = 6, rangesig1 = c(1, 50)) # adjust the rangesig1 range to suit your data
```